# How can I add a exit to the random maze generator?

Tags: unity, c#

This is the maze at runtime. There are some enterences/exists I didn't define yet what is enterence and what is exit. This is one problem to decide but for that I need some how to make at least one path I prefer that it will be a random path each time as part of the maze. Single path with enterence and exit.

The maze as it is not don't have one path that the player/object can move in and exit in another exit.

[image: Random Maze]

Once the maze has generated it's choosing one enterence randomly and put the player/object with a camera facing that enterence/exit

Now the player by controller or by automation should move in and try to find the path to the other side. Before the path finding how I create a path ? I mean I want to keep the random path's without exist but also to make one random path each time that will have also exit.

Than later the path finding ai but first how to generate a path with the maze ?

This is the maze generator script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MazeGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Maze maze;
    public Transform objectToTravel;
    public int mazeWidth;
    public int mazeHeight;
    public string mazeSeed;
    public GameObject wallPrefab;
    public GameObject waypointPrefab;

    private System.Random mazeRG;
    public List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>(); 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        mazeRG = new System.Random();

        if (mazeWidth % 2 == 0)
            mazeWidth++;

            if (mazeHeight % 2 == 0)
            {
                mazeHeight++;
            }

        maze = new Maze(mazeWidth, mazeHeight, mazeRG);
        GenerateMaze();
    }

    public void GenerateMaze()
    {
        var bricks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MazeBrick");
        var waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");

        if (bricks.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach(GameObject brick in bricks)
            {
                Destroy(brick);
            }
        }

        if(waypoints.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach(GameObject waypoint in waypoints)
            {
                Destroy(waypoint);
            }
        }

        positions = new List<Vector3>();

        maze.Generate();
        DrawMaze();
    }

    void DrawMaze()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == true)
                {
                    CreateMaze(position, transform, 0, mazeRG.Next(0, 3) * 90);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == false)
                {
                    var waypoint = Instantiate(waypointPrefab, new Vector3(x , 0, y), Quaternion.identity);
                    waypoint.tag = "Waypoint";


                    if (x == 0 || x == mazeWidth - 1 || y == 0 || y == mazeHeight - 1)
                    {
                        positions.Add(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var randpos = positions[Random.Range(0, positions.Count - 1)];
        objectToTravel.position = randpos;

        if (randpos.z == 0)
        {
            objectToTravel.position = new Vector3(objectToTravel.position.x, objectToTravel.position.y, objectToTravel.position.z - 2);
            objectToTravel.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            objectToTravel.Rotate(0, 0, 0);
        }

        if(randpos.x == 0)
        {
            objectToTravel.position = new Vector3(objectToTravel.position.x - 2, objectToTravel.position.y, objectToTravel.position.z);
            objectToTravel.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            objectToTravel.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
        }

        if(randpos.z == mazeHeight - 1)
        {
            objectToTravel.position = new Vector3(objectToTravel.position.x, objectToTravel.position.y, objectToTravel.position.z + 2);
            objectToTravel.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            objectToTravel.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
        }

        if(randpos.x == mazeWidth - 1)
        {
            objectToTravel.position = new Vector3(objectToTravel.position.x + 2, objectToTravel.position.y, objectToTravel.position.z);
            objectToTravel.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            objectToTravel.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
        }
    }

    void CreateMaze(Vector3 position, Transform parent, int sortingOrder, float rotation)
    {
        GameObject mazePrefab = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        mazePrefab.transform.SetParent(parent);
        mazePrefab.transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotation);
        mazePrefab.tag = "MazeBrick";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        
    }
}
```

The maze class :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Maze
{
    //Grid size
    public int width;
    public int height;

    //Store grid
    private bool[,] grid;
    //Generate random directions to move
    private System.Random rg;

    //Start position
    public int startX;
    public int startY;

    //Public getter
    public bool[,] Grid
    {
        get { return grid; }
    }

    //Constructor of the grid for setting values
    public Maze(int width, int height, System.Random rg)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        this.rg = rg;
    }

    //Generate the grid
    public void Generate()
    {
        grid = new bool[width, height];

        startX = 0;
        startY = 0;

        grid[startX, startY] = true;

        MazeDigger(startX, startY);
    }

    void MazeDigger(int x, int y)
    {
        int[] directions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        //We create random array of directions
        HelpingTools.Shuffle(directions, rg);

        //We are looping over all the directions
        for (int i = 0; i < directions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (directions[i] == 1)
            {
                if (y - 2 < 0)
                continue;

                if (grid[x, y - 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y - 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y - 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y - 2);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 2)
            {
                if (x - 2 < 0)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x - 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x - 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x - 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x - 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 3)
            {
                if (x + 2 > width - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x + 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x + 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x + 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x + 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 4)
            {
                if (y + 2 > height - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x, y + 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y + 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y + 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y + 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And last the Helping Tools class :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HelpingTools : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] array, System.Random rg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = rg.Next(i, array.Length);

            T tempItem = array[randomIndex];

            array[randomIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = tempItem;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: People attempting to answer the question might take note that the maze generated above **is not fully connected**. It is not possible to reach each point from every other point, because there are isolated islands. So when you just place the entrance and exit randomly, there might not be a possible solution.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the actual problem you face is to find an entrance and an exit location which are guaranteed to be connected, so the level is solvable. Is that correct?

Comment: @Philipp true. I want that the player will get lost or will have to walk and find his way but that there will be a way to get from point A to B.

Comment: @Philipp you understood it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be to find a different maze generation algorithm which guarantees that you get a maze where every point on the grid is part of a single connected graph. Or in other words: One where every point is guaranteed to be reachable from every other point. That way it does not matter where you place entrance and exit - there will always be a solution. Wikipedia has [a good overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm) of a couple standard algorithms which fulfill that property.

But if you want to stay with your current algorithm, then a good way to handle it could be to create a list of potential entrance and exit locations in your `MazeDigger` method while you carve a randomized path through the maze. Whenever you land at a point which is on the outer wall of the maze, you put it in a list of potential entrance/exit locations. Then, when the generation is finished, you pick two random points from that list (preferable two points far away from each other, but definitely not the same point twice). Then carve a path from that point to the outside of the maze. These are your entrance and exit.